# er model -> relational model (database)

Tags: relational-database, entity-relationship

I have an e-r model which has following entities: `Doctor, Patient, Human` and there is a generation relationship between `Doctor -> Human` and `Patient -> Human`. I am trying to create an relation model. So, which model is correct: first one or the second one?

1)

```
Human (Name, Surname, Sex, Address)
Doctor(License number, specification)
Patient(Insurance number, diagnosis)
```

2)

```
Doctor(Name, Surname, Sex, Address, License number, specification)
Patient(Name, Surname, Sex, Address, Insurance number, diagnosis)
```

and the entity Human is not necesarry.

P.S. A am new to relational models.

Answer (score 0):

Both models are 'correct'. But there's a difference in inserting and querying the data.

The first one is a good choice when you want to persist your data normalized (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization for more information about normalization). But when you want to query all doctors or all patients for example, you have to join two tables.
Also when you insert a new object you have to insert two rows (into Human and Doctor/Patient).
When you work with an OR-Mapper, which transforms your data into objects you can use polymorphism because you have a common base (Human).

The second possibility is a good choice when speed matters.
It will be faster when you want to query all doctors/patients because no joins are necessary.
But it will be slower when you want to query e.g. all addresses from doctors and patients

Answer (score 0):

This depends largely on your requirements. Can doctors be patients as well? If yes you need a base table like `human`. In that case `doctor` and `patient` should have a foreign key to `human`.

Another option would be to use table inheritance if your DBMS supports that. In PostgreSQL you could e.g. do:

```
create table human 
(
   name text,
   surname text,
   sex char(1),
   address text
);

create table doctor 
(
   license_number integer,
   specifiction text
)
inherits (human);

create table patient
(
   insurance_number integer,
   diagnosis text
)
inherits (human);
```